# TextInputLayout, EditText Hint Animation,Hide Hint

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have an `EditText` that is wrapped within a `TextInputLayout`. After entering text in the first `EditText`, when the focus moves to another input field, I would like to make the hint of the previous `EditText` disappear.

How can I go about achieving this?

Comment: Using `EditText` within `TextInputLayout` is what makes it have a floating label that you want. What is the exact issue that you have?

Comment: Yes it floats the hint, I want the hint to dissappear (off the screen) after focus is lost on that object

Comment: Why has my question been edited? That is not what I am asking.

Comment: Problem is the hint color. It becomes white when typing something. Please change the hint color or change the background color. You will see the hint while typing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want if focus changes from first input field to second one then hint of first should go away. Below is the code which does the same thing.

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/first_text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="hello">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/first_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/first_text_input_layout">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hello" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.gaurav.myapplication;

import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.first_text_input_layout);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_edit_text);

    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
             //Below code will check if editext has focus then show hint 

             //else if it dosen't have focus and user has entered some value only then hide hint.
            if (hasFocus){
                textInputLayout.setHint("hello");
            } else if ( !TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString().trim())){
                textInputLayout.setHint("");

            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: This not what I am asking. Please go look at the original question. Not the edit that has been approved

Comment: You want the hint to disappear when focus goes away from `EditText`? Please correct me If i am wrong.

Comment: No I wish for it to animate to the left